# Installation error in Cocoapods

Tags: ios, google-maps-api-3, cocoapods

I am trying to install cocoapods for my project. And i followed these steps

[image]

But its showing 0 dependencies in podfile. Can anyone tell me what should i do??? And also guide me how to install Google API for my project in order to show list of places in a tableview.

**UPDATED QUESTION**

I have also tried the following steps but still it is not working-

[image]

[image]

Seriously am going crazy right now.Unable to find the mistake. And idea where am i going wrong???

Comment: `you must close your Xcode project that is open` then run pod install again

Comment: installation time close your xcode and try once

Comment: i tried. Still showing same problem :(

Comment: Please show what you have written in `pod` file.

Comment: share you 'podfile' code then it will be easy to sort your exact issue

Comment: nothing for now...what i have to write???

Comment: check my answer below

Comment: Refer below link:
https://www.digifloor.com/install-cocoapods-xcode-project-4-simple-steps-06

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are opened the any `Xcode Project you must close all Xcode project that is already open` and then try the `Pod Install` command , surely works

**Update**

after this command `pod init` Type this command to open the Podfile using Xcode for editing:

**open -a Xcode Podfile**

then you need to add the `pod 'GoogleMaps'` or whatever you need , see the attached image for reference [image]

for step to integration see [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift)

Comment: ok i will try again. But can you guide me for installing Google API??Will it help to show list of  location in Google Map Search engine in my project??

Comment: @pri - I think u missed the one command in between the pod install and pod init

Comment: @pri - really appreciate. do well

Comment: no sir :( i have tried like 3times. I really dunno what should i do next

Comment: @pri - oh no, in which step u struck

Comment: [!] Unable to find a specification for `GoogleMaps`
OSXs-iMac-2:Tattoo (18thJuly) osx$ rm -rf Pods/ Podfile Podfile.lock
OSXs-iMac-2:Tattoo (18thJuly) osx$ pod init
OSXs-iMac-2:Tattoo (18thJuly) osx$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total
pods installed.

[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.

Comment: not stuck actually bt its showing 0 dependency again. Even i have tried this step-  rm -rf Pods/ Podfile Podfile.lock
         $ pod init
         $ pod install

Comment: do one thing remove pods in your xcode project and add again once with the help of https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift , if you face any probelm reply here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117570/discussion-between-pri-and-anbu-karthik).

Answer (score 1):

1.Edit the Podfile and add the following lines.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

2.Save the Podfile.
3.and then locate your project path and use command

```
pod install
```

follow the link for reference

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/start